# Geometric interpretation of the Fundamental group being non-abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

What topological information a fundamental group of a space based at a point carries?

1. It contains information about the number of one dimensional holes in the space.

What other information does it carry?

Do the fundamental group being abelian or non-abelian gives some topological information about the space?

Comment: Well, it's abelian iff it's the homology iff it counts holes.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Then if it's non abelian, it carries other topological information. Right? If yes, what are they?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen To clarify, do you mean: “for any (reasonable) space, the first fundamental group is Abelian if and only if it is isomorphic to the first homology group?” That is an interesting result. Is it well known, e.g. learnable from Hatcher?

Comment: @FShrike correct, for any reasonable enough space (e.g. path connected) the first homology group is the abelianization of the first homotopy group (the "fundamental group"). Any reasonable algebraic topology book will have it (I believe it's in the appendix in Hatcher).

Comment: @Saikat perhaps someone who works in algebraic topology could answer better than me, but there are two obvious problems with answering your (good) question: first, the higher homotopy groups are quite nasty and don't really count higher dimensional holes like higher homology groups do (the magic in 1 dimension comes down to lack of possible obstructions due to dimension letting us equate 1-cycles and loops); second, *every* group is the fundamental group of some space, and we don't have any nice classification of all groups to know what makes then non-abelian (I can't imagine it's computable)

Comment: What I would imagine you could do is work with some nice enough family of non-abelian groups whose abelianizations are computable and known, consider the collection of spaces with those groups as their fundamental groups (minimally up to homotopy equivalence, perhaps a homotopy category of some sort?) and attempt to determine a geometric structure of the spaces from which the abelianizations can be calculated.

Comment: For example, the abelianization of the $n$th dihedral group is either the integers mod $2$ or the Cartesian square of that (depending on the parity of $n$). One could attempt to classify spaces with the dihedral group as their fundamental group and see if these spaces have similarities that yield invariant capturing the non-abelian nature.

Answer (score 2):

There is something to be said about the $2$-cells in the $CW$-structure of the path-component containing the basepoint. Namely, that they include the relations of the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group iff the fundamental group is abelian. I will explain what I mean in more detail. Note that if the space in question is not a $CW$-complex, one could say something about its $CW$-approximations.

Recall that the fundamental group of a $CW$-complex only depends on the $2$-skeleton, so we can really only get information that only depends on the $2$-skeleton. Futhermore, we can also only get information about the path-component of the basepoint.

Let $G$ be a group. Take a presentation of $G$ described as a short exact sequence $$0\to K \to F \to G \to 0$$ where $F$ is a free group and the relations of $G$ are given by $K$. Then $G \cong F/K$ is abelian iff $K$ contains the commutator subgroup of $F$.

Let $X$ be a CW-complex. We assume that $X$ is path-connected since we can only say something about the path-component with the basepoint. The $1$-skeleton $X_1$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circles $X_1 \simeq \bigvee_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}} S^1_\alpha$. These circles correspond to our free generators of $F$ in the short exact sequence and $\pi_1(X_1)\cong F$. The $2$-cells glued to $X_1$ correspond to the relations given in $K$ such that one obtains $\pi_1(X_2)\cong G$. Thus, $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian iff the $2$-cells contains relations generating the commutator subgroup. This what was I meant with the statement.

Let's take a concrete example. Let $T$ denote the torus $S^1\times S^1$. We know that $\pi_1(T)\cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, so $T$ much have some $2$-cells generating the commutator subgroup. The usual example of a $CW$-structure for $T$ is given by one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells, and one $2$-cell, so the $1$-skeleton is a wedge of two circles. The circles correspond to the two generators of the fundamental group of $T$. Let's denote the generators by $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then the $2$-cell is glued to the $1$-skeleton according to the relation $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}$. Note that $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}$ is the commutator of the two generators and generates the commutator subgroup as claimed.